# How to reset a RXJS scan operator based on another Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a component which triggers an `onScrollEnd` event when the last item in a virtual list is rendered. This event will do a new API request to fetch the next page and merge them with the previous results using the `scan` operator.

This component also has a search field which triggers an `onSearch` event.

How do I clear the previous accumulated results from the `scan` operator when a search event is triggered? Or do I need to refactor my logic here?

```
const loading$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
const offset$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);
const search$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

const options$: Observable<any[]> = merge(offset$, search$).pipe(
  // 1. Start the loading indicator.
  tap(() => loading$.next(true)),
  // 2. Fetch new items based on the offset.
  switchMap(([offset, searchterm]) => userService.getUsers(offset, searchterm)),
  // 3. Stop the loading indicator.
  tap(() => loading$.next(false)),
  // 4. Complete the Observable when there is no 'next' link.
  takeWhile((response) => response.links.next),
  // 5. Map the response.
  map(({ data }) =>
    data.map((user) => ({
      label: user.name,
      value: user.id
    }))
  ),
  // 6. Accumulate the new options with the previous options.
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    // TODO: Dont merge on search$.next 
    return [...acc, ...curr]);
  }
);

// Fetch next page
onScrollEnd: (offset: number) => offset$.next(offset);
// Fetch search results
onSearch: (term) => {
  search$.next(term);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a working solution: I check the current offset by using `withLatestFrom` before the `scan` operator and reset the accumulator if needed based on this value.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-search-offset)

Comment: This is indeed a very concise, clean solution.

Answer (score 12):

To manipulate the `state` of a `scan` you can write [higher order functions](https://dev.to/damcosset/higher-order-functions-in-javascript-4j8b) that get the old state and the new update. Combine then with the [merge](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) operator. This way you stick to a clean stream-oriented solution without any side-effects.

```js
const { Subject, merge } = rxjs;
const { scan, map } = rxjs.operators;

add$ = new Subject();
clear$ = new Subject();

add = (value) => (state) => [...state, value];
clear = () => (state) => [];

const result$ = merge(
  add$.pipe(map(add)),
  clear$.pipe(map(clear))
).pipe(
  scan((state, innerFn) => innerFn(state), [])
)

result$.subscribe(result => console.log(...result))

add$.next(1)
add$.next(2)
clear$.next()
add$.next(3)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

This method can easily be extended and/or adapted for other `state` usecases in rxjs.

**Example (remove last item)**

```
removeLast$ = new Subject()

removeLast = () => (state) => state.slice(0, -1);

merge(
  ..
  removeLast$.pipe(map(removeLast)),
  ..
)
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, how does `value` get in `innerFn`?

Comment: If you check the `add` function. The `value` is the param that is given when the function is called the **first** time at `add$.pipe(map(add))`. This function call returns a function itself - `(state) => [...state, value])` - that now is the value of the `Observable`. The previously returned function is then called the **second** time at every `scan` as `innerFn`. This is all possible as `functions` are `first-class citizen` in Javascript like `strings`, `numbers`, `boolean` and so on.

Answer (score 7):

I think you could achieve what you want just by restructuring your chain (I'm omitting `tap` calls that trigger loading for simplicity):

```
search$.pipe(
  switchMap(searchterm =>
    concat(
      userService.getUsers(0, searchterm),
      offset$.pipe(concatMap(offset => userService.getUsers(offset, searchterm)))),
    ).pipe(
      map(({ data }) => data.map((user) => ({
        label: user.name,
        value: user.id
      }))),
      scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Every emission from `search$` will create a new inner Observable with its own `scan` that will start with an empty accumulator.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Martin. I didn't get it to fully work as I wanted using your solution but it provided some inspiration and I found a working solution. You can check it out here, let me now if you think it can be improved: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-search-offset

Comment: TBH I believe this is the best solution. It keeps everything stream-oriented and doesn't rely on anything other than the stream itself to reset the scan.

Comment: This is the best solution but I couldn't get this working in my app. The observable stream was never subscribed and no calls were fired, I implemented using different approach. But this is cleaner, I may have to retry this when deadline is little flexible.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting stream. Thinking about it, offset$ and search$ are really 2 separate streams, though, with different logic, and so should be merged at the very end and not the beginning.

Also, it seems to me that searching should reset the offset to 0, and I don't see that in the current logic.

So here's my idea:

```
const offsettedOptions$ = offset$.pipe(
    tap(() => loading$.next(true)),    
    withLatestFrom(search$),
    concatMap(([offset, searchterm]) => userService.getUsers(offset, searchterm)),
    tap(() => loading$.next(false)),
    map(({ data }) =>
    data.map((user) => ({
      label: user.name,
      value: user.id
    })),
    scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr])
);

const searchedOptions$ = search$.pipe(
    tap(() => loading$.next(true)),
    concatMap(searchTerm => userService.getUsers(0, searchterm)),
    tap(() => loading$.next(false)),
    map(({ data }) =>
    data.map((user) => ({
      label: user.name,
      value: user.id
    })),
);

const options$ = merge(offsettedOptions, searchedOptions);
```

See if that works or would make sense. I may be missing some context.

Comment: Thanks for responding Jesse. I didn't get it to fully work as I wanted using your solution but it provided some inspiration and I found a working solution. You can check it out here, let me now if you think it can be improved: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-search-offset

Answer (score 0):

I know its old, but I just needed to do the same thing and have another solution to throw in to the mix.

There are really just 2 actions the user can trigger

```
const search$ = new Subject<string>();
const offset$ = new Subject<number>();
```

We don't really care about `offset$` until `search$` emits, and at that point, we want it to be 0 to start over. I would write it like this:

```
const results$ = search$.pipe( // Search emits
  switchMap((searchTerm) => {
    return offset$.pipe( // Start watching offset
      startWith(0),  // We want a value right away, so set it to 0
      switchMap((offset) => {
        return userService.getUsers(offset, searchTerm)) // get the stuff
      })
    )
  }))
```

At this point we are resetting the offset every time `search$` emits, and any time `offset$` emits we make a fresh api call fetching the desired resources. We need the collection to reset if `search$` emits, so I believe the right place is inside `switchMap` wrapping the `offset$` pipe.

```
const results$ = search$.pipe( // Search emits
  switchMap((searchTerm) => {
    return offset$.pipe( // Start watching offset
      startWith(0),  // We want a value right away, so set it to 0
      switchMap((offset) => {
        return userService.getUsers(offset, searchTerm)) // get the stuff
      }),
      takeWhile((response) => response.links.next), // stop when we know there are no more.
      // Turn the data in to a useful shape
      map(({ data }) => 
        data.map((user) => ({
          label: user.name,
          value: user.id
        }))
      ),
      // Append the new data with the existing list
      scan((list, response) => {
        return [  // merge
          ...list,
          ...response
        ]
      }, [])
    )
  }))
```

This great part here is that the scan is reset on every new `search$` emission.

The final bit here, I would move `loading$` out of tap, and declare it separately. Final code should look something like this

```
const search$ = new Subject<string>();
const offset$ = new Subject<number>();
let results$: Observable<{label: string; value: string}[]>;

results$ = search$.pipe( // Search emits
  switchMap((searchTerm) => {
    return offset$.pipe( // Start watching offset
      startWith(0),  // We want a value right away, so set it to 0
      switchMap((offset) => {
        return userService.getUsers(offset, searchTerm)) // get the stuff
      }),
      takeWhile((response) => response.links.next), // stop when we know there are no more.
      // Turn the data in to a useful shape
      map(({ data }) => 
        data.map((user) => ({
          label: user.name,
          value: user.id
        }))
      ),
      // Append the new data with the existing list
      scan((list, response) => {
        return [  // merge
          ...list,
          ...response
        ]
      }, [])
    )
  }));

const loading$ = merge(
  search$.pipe(mapTo(true)), // set to true whenever search emits
  offset$.pipe(mapTo(true)),  // set to true when offset emits
  results$.pipe(mapTo(false)), // set to false when we get new results
);

results$.subscribe((results) => {
  console.log(results);
})
```