# How can I reset a scan operator or stream?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs6

```
message$ = new Subject();

method(type) {
    return this.message$.pipe(
        filter((element) => element.type === type),
        scan((acc, val) => [...acc, val], [])
    )
}

method.subscribe()
```

I would like reset my stream in part of scan action from another method.

```
 reset() {
   // reset logic
}
```

If I try to reset message with message$.next() it still doesn't reset scun, but makes the reset value part of the stream.

How could I can to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset a RXJS scan operator based on another Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330324/how-to-reset-a-rxjs-scan-operator-based-on-another-observable)

Comment: May be but I've got more better answer for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy solution, once you understand the concept. You can move the logic that updates your state inside the scan to a [higher order function](https://dev.to/damcosset/higher-order-functions-in-javascript-4j8b) and combine multiple different state interactions using the [merge](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) operator.

```js
const { Subject, merge } = rxjs;
const { scan, map } = rxjs.operators;

message$ = new Subject();
reset$ = new Subject();

add = (message) => (state) => [...state, message];
clear = () => (state) => [];

const result$ = merge(
  // The function add is applied to message$ and the outer function is called with the message value
  message$.pipe(map(add)),
  // The function clear is applied to reset$ and the outer function is called
  reset$.pipe(map(clear))
).pipe(
  // The inner function is now fn. In case of add its now: (state) => [...state, message]
  // The function is called with the previous state and the new update is now the value of the scan.
  scan((state, fn) => fn(state), [])
)

result$.subscribe(console.log)

message$.next("Hello")
message$.next("Goodbye")
reset$.next()
message$.next("Hello again!")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

You can use this solution for every state manipulation with `scan`. The functions you write to manipulate the `scan-state` are not limited. One more example could be a function where you only delete the last value:

```
// Subject to trigger
const deleteLastValue = new Subject();

// Function that manipulates the state
const deleteLast = () => (state) => state.slice(0, -1)

// Apply the function to the observable/subject.
deleteLastValue$.pipe(map(deleteLast))
```